# debug c++ in VS Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I try to debug c++ in VS Code.

```
  "D:\cmin> cmd /C "c:\Users\X\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-1.1.0-insiders2\debugAdapters\bin\WindowsDebugLauncher.exe --stdin=Microsoft-MIEngine-In-rwihouip.f54 --stdout=Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-2lane3zl.twt --stderr=Microsoft-MIEngine-Error-wefv1bki.4gf --pid=Microsoft-MIEngine-Pid-ya414q3l.eps --dbgExe=C:\MinGW64\bin\gdb.exe --interpreter=mi "
    'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have no idea what can I do more. I did everything I found in this matter

Comment: This is weird. cmd.exe should be in your `PATH` because its in the OS folders.

Comment: have you tried going in System properties -> advanced -> Enviromental Variables, and check if the PATH includes system32?